# one Google Sheets macro for all cells

Tags: google-sheets, macros

Good afternoon.
Help me solve the problem.
I have a table (screen added), each row has a checkbox. After a checkbox is true, the macro copies the cells from that checkbox's row to a separate sheet.

[image]

I can write a script for each line, but it takes a lot of time. Help create a macro for the entire range of table rows. Thank you!!!

Comment: Can you share a sample dummy sheet for proper replication of your actual sheet? See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

You can update your macro.gs file with this custom script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.value == 'TRUE') {
    const sheetNameDestination = 'Sheet2'; //Change this sheet name to your actual destination sheet

    var source = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.getRow(), 1, 1, e.range.getColumn() - 1);
    var destination = e.source.getSheetByName(sheetNameDestination).getRange(e.source.getSheetByName('Sheet2').getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, source.getValues()[0].length);
    
    source.copyTo(destination)
  }
};
```

**Demo:**

[image: check this sample]

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**